# How can I overload the 'as' operator for custom types?

Tags: casting, rust

I have two simple classes representing four ints and four floats. I would like to overload the 'as' operator so that I can easily convert one to the other. This should be done by converting each of the elements individually. So far I have:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct i32x4 {
    pub x: i32,
    pub y: i32,
    pub z: i32,
    pub w: i32
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct f32x4 {
    pub x: f32,
    pub y: f32,
    pub z: f32,
    pub w: f32
}

impl f32x4 {    
    pub fn as_i32x4(&mut self) -> i32x4 {
        i32x4{x: self.x as i32, y: self.y as i32, z: self.z as i32, w: self.w as i32}
    }
}
```

This lets me do:

```
let mut f = f32x4{x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.0};
let i = f.as_i32x4(); // <-- Using my conversion function
```

But I want to do:

```
let mut f = f32x4{x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.0};
let i = f as i32x4; // <-- Using the 'as' operator
```

Which gives:

> error: non-scalar cast: `simd::f32x4` as `simd::i32x4`

Is it possible to get the syntax I am hoping for? I found some traits (AsRef, AsMut, From, Into) in '[std::convert](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/index.html)' but it's not quite clear to me if they are what I want?

Thanks!

P.S. I am aware there is real SIMD functionality in the pipeline, but it's not stable yet so I'm just working round/emulating this with my own classes. And learning, obviously ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot overload `as`.

If you want to express "conversion" in some reasonably standard fashion, you'll want to implement one or more of the traits you indicated.  Specifically:

- `AsMut`/`AsRef`: pointers of this type and some other type are safely interchangeable (exactly the same binary layout and invariants).
- `From`/`Into`: it is possible to convert between this type and some other type without possibility of failure or additional context (both types are the same "thing", just expressed/encoded/typed differently).

To be honest, I'm not entirely sure *what* semantics you're expecting.  There is also the [`conv`](https://crates.io/crates/conv) crate that defines some additional traits:

> *Disclaimer*: I am the author of the aforementioned `conv` crate.

- `ApproxFrom`/`ApproxInto`: values of one type can be converted to some other type via one or more approximation schemes.
- `ValueFrom`/`ValueInto`: values of one type can *mostly* be converted without loss of information to some other type (*i.e.* there is a possibility of failure).
- `TryFrom`/`TryInto`: values of one type can *potentially* be converted to some other type *somehow* (*i.e.* best-effort conversions).

Depending on what you're trying to do, `ApproxFrom`/`ApproxInto` make the most sense for converting values (you may need to do rounding), with `AsMut`/`AsRef` being defensible if you're trying to do float↔integer tricks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The behaviour of (e.g) 'let i: i32 = some_float as i32' is well defined and I would simply expect to apply this operation to each of the four members (as shown in my as_i32x4() function).

From what you have said, it seems that From/Into would be most appropriate, or possibly ApproxFrom/ApproxInto.

Thanks again!

Comment: @DavidWilliams: Actually, it *really* isn't.  What's `std::f32::NAN as i32`?  There's no answer that makes sense, and what you get changes depending on your optimisation level.  You can even use this to violate memory safety *without* `unsafe` code.  See [Issue 10184](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/10184#issuecomment-139858153).  This is actually partly *why* I wrote `conv`: to define a set of conversions that were, at minimum, *well defined* and consistent.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting bug. Still, this ability to cast between int/float with 'as' already exists in Rust (regardless of what that behavior is), would it not make sense to allow this 'accepted' behavior to be extended to sets of ints/floats? As a programmer I know which numbers to not try and convert (maybe, and I can imagine only one element may fail to convert, what then?). And even if not, it's really a flaw in my specific use case - in general are there not cases where it would make sense to allow the user to overload 'as' for certain types? Anyway, great feedback.

Comment: For `AsMut` and `AsRef`, the Rustonomicon claims that two types, even if they are identical, **cannot** be trusted to have the same binary layout (though in practice they should be expected to). Is this wrong or does implementing those traits convince rustc to make them the same or something? https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/repr-rust.html

Comment: @Jsor: It's not wrong: you should *usually* only implement `AsRef`/`AsMut` when you *know* you'll have the same binary layout.  As in, either the exact same type (*i.e.* you're `AsRef<i32>`-ing a struct to one of its fields which is an `i32`, *or* you've used `repr` attributes to control the layout.